# Creating registerable Visual Studio packages

Tags: visual-studio

I'm creating a single file generator for Visual Studio (similar to the LINQ to SQL/ LINQ to Entities generators). I've follewed the example in the Visual Studio 2008 SDK (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sfgdd), but I've hit a snag with `regpkg`, I can't work out how to get it working.

I can't find any good example of how it needs to be done, the examples seem to think I have a `.reg` file already, but I don't know what I need in the `.reg` to do it.

Can someone fill in the gap in the examples documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem, using an Installer project within Visual Studio to set up the registry keys. In addition to that you need to have the DLL installed into the GAC.

I'll be doing a series on my blog which covers this, starting with the registry keys: http://www.aaron-powell.com/blog/june-2009/creating-an-installer-for-a-single-file-generator---part-1.aspx